# V.Net.Allpairs not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network-analysis

I have two layers: (1) point layer (city centroids) and (2) OSM road shapefile layer. I want to know the distance to take from one city to another. I want to output a matrix like this:

```
from\to         3       4       5
1   0       18820.386   17206.651   17373.274
3   18820.386   0       1739.079    9040.575
4   17206.651   1739.079    0       7426.84
5   17373.274   9040.575    7426.84     0
```

I just do not get the instructions found here https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.allpairs.html

How can I do this inside QGIS?